# How to get asterisk (*) and hash (#) from Amazon lex to Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

Lets assume customer say 0 to 9 to perform some task in Amazon connect call. this is my lex box. Whatever the customer say it will process and return the value in **userinput** slot.

**Amazon Lex Bot**

[image: Lex Bot]

**Amazon Connect Flow**

[image: Amazon Connect Flow]

So I can get the value in connect using the lex slot name. Its working fine for numbers and alphabets.

But how to get the special characters like asterisk (*) and hash (#) Kindly help me out

Comment: Did you try to use the "Get Customer Input" box but instead of Lex, use DTMF? Then pass that to Lex. If you don't want to do it in Connect and only in Lex, then you will probably need to parse the userInput for the words "asterisk" or "hash", as well as the ways Connect's speech-to-text interprets those inputs.

Comment: lex slot is not accepting special characters

Comment: @Boopathikumar did you ever have a solution? From my tests, user pressing # or * seems to interrupt/cancel the input. And I either only get * or only the numbers BEFORE the # or * was pressed

Answer (score 0):

Adding special characters in AWS Lex can be a pain sometimes but there is a way to get around it.

Adding them as an utterance wouldn't work so we will be using custom slots type instead.

Assuming you've already created a bot and your intent is ready, the next step would be to create a custom slot type.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnDUu.jpg][1]

The next step would be to fill all the fields by selecting restrict to slot values and synonyms. Enter any value in the first column and enter '*' or whatever special character you'd need in the synonyms field.

Click on add slot to intent.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vGyc.jpg][2]

Create a slot and the slot type you just made to it.

Finally, add the slot to the utterance, and once you've done that it would work.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4ONJ.jpg][3]

Another more complicated way to do this would be to make a Lex Lambda function and close/elicit the intent based on what 'inputTranscripts' you'd get from the lex bot as an event.

Comment: not able to add images for some reason so refer the links